# Stateful Session Bean injection JSF error

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm coding an app using JSF and Hibernate.

This is the problem i get when i call the register method of "RegisterForm" :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Could
>   not find SFSB UserFlow with {[118, 76, 77, 121, 103, 95, 68, -127,
>   -113, 12, -89, 25, -42, 103, 81, -61]}    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

Here is the three classes that are cosing the problem:

**RegisterForm:**

```
@ManagedBean(name="registerForm")
@RequestScoped
public class RegisterForm {
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userSession.uf}")
private UserFlow uf;

public String register(){
uf.register(nom, prenom, username, password1);
return "Perso";

}
```

**userSession:**

```
@ManagedBean(name="userSession")
@SessionScoped
public class UserSession {

    @EJB
    UserFlow uf;


    public UserSession(){       
    }


    public UserFlow getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(UserFlow uf) {
        this.uf= uf;
    }
```

**and UserFlow:**

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class UserFlow implements UserFlowRemote {


    private State state;
    private User u;


    @EJB
    GestionReleve g;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public UserFlow() {
        state=State.UNKNOWN;
        u=null;
    }

    public void register(String nom, String prenom, String email, String password){ 
    /* Here we register the object in the DB with em.persist(object); */
    }
    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public User getU() {
        return u;
    }
    }
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: I don't have another class with the same name in another package. I tried it anyway ... nothing :(

Comment: It's not usually safe to try to inject a field from an `@SessionScoped` bean, due to lifecycle timing issues. You should try injecting the session bean alone first, and then pulling what you want from there. Or you could directly inject the EJB into the target bean (I'm not sure why you're doing this thing you have here in the first place)